# Why is the constraint $\mbox{rank} (X) \leq r$ non-convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-rank, constraints, non-convex-optimization

I have a problem claiming that the set of solutions of the minimization problem of a convex objective function on this rank constraint is non-convex since the constraint is non-convex.

Note that $X$ is of dimension $m \times n$ and the constraint arises so that we can write $X=AB'$, where $A$ is $m \times r$ and $B$ is $n \times r$.

Comment: Note that the rank function is just the $\ell^0$ pseudo norm on the singular values. The $\ell^0$ pseudo norm is not convex.

Comment: $x=\pm 1$ has rank 1 but the average has rank 0.

Comment: Presumably $r$ is non zero and less than the dimension of the ambient space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Let $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix}, B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Whay is $rank(A), rank(B)$? What about the rank of a convex linear combination?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the mid-point (a convex combination) of
$$
\begin{pmatrix}I_r\\&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\&I_r\end{pmatrix}
$$
gives you a rank $>r$ matrix.